# Disable stoppropagation inside specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is code where I want to enable stoppropagation on the class "Object" cause stop propagation I have used for modal class, to prevent close popup. And stoppropagation on the modal class has killed the javascript function in the 'object' class, so I have to prevent the stoppropagation function on the object class, so that the javascript inside the object class can work. Is there any solution? thank you so much. [detil modal popup, codepin](https://codepen.io/designcouch/pen/obvKxm)

```js
$('.button').click(function() {
      var buttonId = $(this).attr('id');
      $('#modal-container').removeAttr('class').addClass(buttonId);
      $('body').addClass('modal-active');
    })

    $('#modal-container').click(function() {
      $(this).addClass('out');
      $('body').removeClass('modal-active');
    });

    $('.modal').click(function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

```html
 <div id="one" class="button">Button</div> 
   <div id="modal-container">
      <div class="modal-background">
        <div class="modal">
          <div class="object">
            <h2>Record your voice</h2>
            <button>Press To Record</button>
            <span>00:00</span>
            <button>Send</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: there is no .button element in your markup. so this codes does not make a lot of sense. did you forget something to post?

Comment: I have edited,
Thank you so much

Comment: My guess is that you only want to `stopPropagation` if `e.target` is a button so you can check `e.target.tagName` or any other html element property to identify if the user clicked something like record or send or the user clicked the model to close it. You can also add a close button and you should also close the model if the user clicks the background.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, your sugest make my problem solved